# How to remove ice maker from Miele / Liebherr freezer?

Tags: repair, appliances, refrigerator

I have a Miele KFN 8701 SE freezer (also known as a Liebherr freezer) which has an ice-maker which has failed.

---

A plastic part has come free, and also what looks like a temperature sensor:

[image: Plastic part loose]

---

This is the front view. It seems to sit on a holding bracket from above, and there appear to be lugs that would let it drop down if I could move it forwards a centimetre or so. However it doesn't seem to want to move.

[image: Front of ice-maker]

---

There is a single screw that I can see, which I don't seem to be able to undo (there isn't much room for a screwdriver). However I'm not sure whether this is holding the thing in place or not. It looks to be a fair way from the mounting brackets.

[image: Left side of ice-maker]

---

If I could remove it, I might be able to repair it, or just leave it out and make ice cubes the old-fashioned way.

Does anyone know how to remove this thing?

Answer (score 5):

I worked it out after [watching a YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YhkRNnXlvhc) about the Liebherr CS 2061 Ice maker Tray replacement. Apparently my Miele freezer is a Liebherr freezer re-badged.

---

### How to remove

There are two retaining lugs in the middle (from the point of view of front to back).

[image: Ice maker]

(Ice maker is upside down in this photo and the next one).

[image: Ice maker again]

---

These engage against two moveable lugs at the top of the freezer, circled:

[image: Top of freezer]

Use a couple of chopsticks or screwdrivers to push both lugs up simultaneously, whilst pulling the ice-maker towards you (having two people might help). When the lugs release it should slide out forwards.

---

[image: Control cable]

There is a control cable on top, prise the rubber covering aside, and then slide the connector upwards. Then the ice-maker can be completely removed.

---

The (outside) screw visible in the second picture is not relevant to removing the ice-maker. It holds the motor in place.

---

### To replace

Re-attach the control cable, and then slide the ice-maker firmly back into place. The lugs should snap back into position to retain it.